# I think I accidentally programmed my Asus laptop to auto shut down

Tags: windows-10, windows-task-scheduler

I have problems with web browsing instead of sleeping so I installed the top comment task scheduler solution here:

https://superuser.com/a/740780/705502

I think I made a mistake with the timing or something because now my laptop is stuck on a black screen when the airport mode light on.

I once held the power button for a really long time and it booted up and got as far to my desktop screen but I looked away and it went Black again.

Now the closest I have gotten in the Asus logo showing up but now I can't even get that far.

Comment: Try to boot into safemode. This should prevent the task to be run and can then be adjusted/removed.

Comment: How do I boot on safe mode. Currently the power button and airplane mode button are both on. When I hold power for 14 seconds it turns off but then both lights come back on the moment I let go of the button.

Comment: @JimHarbor - Use “Advanced Startup” option within Windows

Answer (score 1):

Normally, holding the power button until shutdown **completely** shuts the PC.

You write, "When I hold power for 14 seconds it turns off but then both lights come back on the moment I let go of the button." This indicates that perhaps there is an incomplete update, or a hardware issue, since you dn't even get the Asus startup logo.

A few things to try:

1. Hold down the power button 15 seconds or so, press immediately to start up again, and then hold down the power button again. Repeat that cycle three times, and *if* Windows is able too, [it will start in Safe Mode](https://www.drivereasy.com/knowledge/how-to-enter-safe-mode-in-windows-10/#w1).
2. On another machine, make a rescue USB device, such as a [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10), [Hiren’s BootCD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/hbcd-v152/), or [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/hiren39s-bootcd/). [Enter BIOS](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-access-asus-laptop-bios) and try to reinstall Windows 10, keeping files, or perform other repairs.
3. If you cannot even enter BIOS, the laptop likely needs professional repair.

Comment: I tried the Safe Mode loop. Didn't work. I purposely let the battery drain. Now when it's unplugged no lights are on and it doesn't turn on. When it is plugged in, the power and airplane mode lights are on like before. Which BIOS file should I use? The back of the computer says "UX331F Notebook PC" bit the Asus download center gas multiple models that start with UX331F

Comment: Update: I pulled the UX331FA Bios and put it on a fat32 USB drive as a .bin file. I am hitting Ctrl R repeatedly but can't get the bios install screen

Comment: No one suggested changing BIOS. If it was working, do not change it. **Enter** the BIOS **settings** to allow boot from USB.

Comment: I couldn't enter Bios was the issue